# Gaming Questions of the Week #1

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to get the blog going again I'm looking for:

### **the most awesome question or answer of the week**

Hot questions tend to be great candidates, though some awesome content manages to fly by under the radar. Some great examples are:

- [Why do console games require a button press before showing the main menu?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18780/10)
- [What is kiting?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18903/10)
- [What mistakes cost you games when you were Bronze/Silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18710/10)

Please post any question that you feel is worthy and explain why. Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

### [Read the blog post here!](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/minecraft-2/small-world-not-quite)

Comment: Loving the edit party going on here. ♪

Answer (score 4):

This one seems to qualify.

[What happens when you reach the edge of the world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)